# Trying to run loop iterations in parallel in Groovy - getting errors

Tags: multithreading, groovy

I have a list of hundreds of thousands of tasks that needs to be done (in any order). It takes several hours to run through them all. I figure a good way of speeding it up would be to try running it in parallel.

Here's a minimal reproduction of the code that's single threaded and works fine:

```
doTask = { more ->
    println("Start")
    sleep 10000  // sleep 10 seconds
    println("Finish")
}

(1..3).each{ more -> doTask(more) }
```

I have no prior experience with Groovy so this functional syntax is a bit alien to me... but I found a lot of questions on SO where people suggested that you check this page:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Concurrency+with+Groovy

Linkrot has occured - that page no longer exists, but I did find an archive of it here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150102212441/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Concurrency+with+Groovy

I tried adapting the examples from that page and ended up with this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*

pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)

defer = {c -> pool.submit(c as Callable) }
doTask = { more ->
    println("Start")
    sleep 10000 // sleep 10 seconds
    println("Finish")
}

(1..3).each{ more -> defer{doTask(more)} }
```

When I run it over here:
http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

I get this error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:5)
    at Script1$_run_closure3.doCall(Script1.groovy:12)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:12)
```

What's going on? Have I somehow messed up the syntax? Am I misusing an API? Is this maybe just a limitation of that website?

Comment: You're trying to create threads on VM that is on some other machine - that can be easily used to bring the site down, so they removed permissions for webconsole. Try running it locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this code runs fine for me... the Exception is probably because the appspot webconsole you're using does not allow multi-threaded applications to run.

Download Groovy and run it with the [Groovy Console](http://groovy-lang.org/groovyconsole.html), it will work fine.

But here's a suggestion for simplifying your code a little bit:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 )

doTask = { more ->
    println "Start"
    sleep 10000 // sleep 10 seconds
    println "Finish"
}

( 1..3 ).each { more -> pool.submit { doTask( more ) } }
```

In Groovy, anything between curly braces is a closure you can submit to the pool.

So `pool.submit { /* any code here to run async */ }` works.

Comment: Thanks! I figured there was probably a way to simply and remove that `defer` function, but I had bigger concerns about how I was getting exceptions to deal with first. I downloaded Groovy and ran the code in the console. It worked! (My code is actually running on a headless server is the only reason I didn't install groovy already.)

Comment: You could even avoid the pool by using Java 8's `parallelStream`: `( 1..3 ).parallelStream().map { more -> doTask( more ) }.toArray()` (toArray() is necessary because `map()` is lazy).

Comment: Not sure what version of Java/Groovy is being used (there's a complicated lot of layers for me to reach the actual VM I'm running on... it's embedded in an executable in an executable on a remote machine off somewhere...). I'm trying to stick with APIs that have been around for forever to minimize the chances of accidentally using something that's too new...